# stop sprites from going through each other

Tags: java, position, sprite

In the game that I am making I want to make it so that the zombies can't walk through each other or the player.

I don't want to make it so that the zombies stop for a while or move in another direction when they hit each other because it looks weird and I want the zombies to follow the player always. What I was thinking was to keep track of the zombies x and y position before (which I'm already doing) and then when it collides with another zombie or the player it will teleport to the last x and y position before it collided with another sprite.

Would this work? Is there a better way to do it on? And how would I keep track of the latest x and y position before the zombie collided with another sprite?

I already have the code that hecks the collision for the zombies

```
for(int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++){
            Zombie z = (Zombie) zombies.get(i);
            Rectangle r2 = z.getBounds();
            for(int j = i + 1; j < zombies.size(); j++){
                Zombie z2 = (Zombie) zombies.get(j);
                Rectangle r1 = z2.getBounds();
                if(r2.intersects(r1)){
                    //the code for stoping the sprites from going through each other should be here
                }
            }
        }
```

I am just wondering what I should have in the if statement to make the sprites not going through each other.

Comment: What is it with Zombies lately? You're the second person today who asks about making a Zombie game, I am writing a Zombie story myself, then there's 'Plants vs. Zombies'...anyway. You need to create classes. Each object of a 'sprite class' has X/Y coordinates. If one of the sprites moves, you could either iterate through all the other sprites (and thereby check if there's a collision) OR keep a 2-dimensional tile map which does it for you. How is your game field organized?

Comment: Don't ask another question if [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218651/how-to-stop-entities-sprites-from-going-through-each-other) doesn't get enough attention or, at least, delete your older question. The teleporting to the last position seems rather raw. If you're not going to allow the passing through (as many games do) at least don't let the zombies move to an occupied position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do collision checking and movement at the same time:

```
for(int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++){
    Zombie z = (Zombie) zombies.get(i);

    // New code here:
    int x = z.getX();
    int y = z.getY();
    attemptZombieMove(z);

    Rectangle r2 = z.getBounds();
    for(int j = 0; j < zombies.size(); j++){
        if (i == j) {
            continue;
        }
        Zombie z2 = (Zombie) zombies.get(j);
        Rectangle r1 = z2.getBounds();
        if(r2.intersects(r1)){
            //the code for stoping the sprites from going through each other should be here
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I changed the inner `for` loop so that `j` starts from 0. I did that because we want to change the zombie's position in the middle of the loop. So it's possible that when we check zombie A for collisions it might not collide with zombie B, but after B moves they collide.

Your collision detection could just reset `z`'s x and y values to the `int`s you grabbed before attempting to move `z`. You can make it more sophisticated than that though - reset x if there is a collision in x, and reset y if there is a collision in y (resetting both if there is a collision in both). That way the zombie could hit another zombie or a wall or something and walk along it.

One suggestion would be to make the ticks short enough that each zombie only moves a pixel in each tick. That way, making it so the zombie doesn't move doesn't set it back that far, and there only needs to be a one-pixel gap between zombies for them to all head toward the player at full speed. If you combine that with a collision box that is smaller by one pixel, then you should get the desired density of zombies while they are moving.

Also, you can make `Zombie` extend a `CollidableObject` class, and then have the inner loop iterate through a collection of `CollidableObject`s that would include all the zombies. That way you can also write a `Wall` class, an `Obstacle` class, etc., have them all extend `CollidableObject`, and stick more objects into the `CollidableObject` list, and collisions with zombies and obstacles would all be taken care of in one loop.

Comment: How should the `attemptZombieMove(z)` method look like for it to work?

Comment: Get the zombie's current position, figure out where it should go (I assume toward the player, though you could include more sophisticated behavior if desired), then change the zombie's x and y values.

Comment: could it look like this? `for(int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++){ 
                Zombie z = (Zombie) zombies.get(i);
                if(z.getY() > player.getY()){
                    z.setY(z.getY() - .3);
                }
                if(z.getY() < player.getY()){
                    z.setY(z.getY() + .3);
                }
                if(z.getX() > player.getX()){
                    z.setX(z.getX() - .3);
                }
                if(z.getX() < player.getX()){
                    z.setX(z.getX() + .3);
                }`

Comment: `if(z.isAlive()){
                    z.move();
                }else{ 
                    zombies.remove(i);
                }
            }`

Comment: As I have it in my example, `attemptZombieMove(z)` would be for just one zombie at a time. So yes, but don't use the loop. Otherwise you might move all the zombies, figure out zombie A doesn't collide with anything, then figure out zombie B does collide with something, and move B back into a position which would mean A and B have collided.

Answer (score 1):

As a little suggestion for the tile option:

Assuming that your game field is organized as a 16x16 tilemap, it may look like this:

```
Tile Map[16][16];
```

Now if your sprite moves, you will know which tile you want to go.

```
if(Map[NewX][NewY].Occupant == NULL) {
    Map[NewX][NewY].Occupant = Sprite;
    Map[Sprite.X][Sprite.Y].Occupant = NULL;
    Sprite.setLocation(NewX, NewY);
}
```

The `Tile` contains a pointer to an object of type `Sprite` (or whatever you want to call it) called `Occupant`. This little theory will allow you to easily check, whether the field you want to go to already is occupied...or moves if it isn't.

The Zombie will stop moving if the field in question is already occupied.

Comment: This is not Java syntax

Comment: @RobWatts Pardon me, I'm from the C++ corner and haven't done Java for a while. Java doesn't have explicit pointers, does it? Lemme correct that.